# Magento category count

Tags: magento-1.7

I would like to have Magento display the total count of the products including the products in subcategories. Eg. if the Main category has two products and a subcategory has five products.

I.e.:

- MAIN CATEGORY (12)
- SUB CATEGORY A (5)
- SUB CATEGORY B (5)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code.

```
   <ul>               
          <?php 
           // This is category id 
           $id = 42;

           $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
           $subcats = $cat->getChildren();
           foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid):
           $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
           if($_category->getIsActive()):  
                $productCount = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getProductCount();?>

         <li><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL();?>"><span><?php echo $_category->getName();?>
<?php echo '('.$productCount.')'?></span></a></li>

        <?php endif;
         endforeach;?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can use this function.

```
public function getProductCount($category) 
{ 
$prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel(’catalog/product_collection’)->addCategoryFilter($category); 
Mage::getSingleton(’catalog/product_status’)->addVisibleFilterToCollection($prodCollection); 
Mage::getSingleton(’catalog/product_visibility’)->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($prodCollection); 
return $prodCollection->count(); 
}
```